# Обработка исключений C++

Tags: c++, исключения

Есть одна исключительная ситуация, но нужно чтобы на нее было 2 разных реакции.

```
 void f1() {

        //throw ситуация 1
    }

    void f2() {
        //throw ситуация 1
    } 
int main() {
    try
    {
        /*
        .
        .
        .
        */
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        //реакция на ситуация 1
        //в f1()
    }
    catch (...) {
        //реакция на ситуация 1
        //в f2()
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Класс ошибки должен быть один, но при этом в `catch` реакции разные. Когда ситуация противоположна этой(возникают 2 разные ситуации, но ловится одном `cathc`), я понимаю как реализовать. Есть догадка что это делается с помощью полиморфизма, но пока что я не понимаю как.

Comment: Класс ошибки должен быть два ну или в этом классе хранить соответствующее поле с видом ошибки

Comment: Enum заведите, и в классе порожденном от exception добавьте поле с этим enum, хотя сомнительно что это удобнее чем два класса. А в catch соответственно вставить switch(..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть разные варианты...

- код функций не ваш, вы не можете его менять.

Либо обертываем каждый вызов `f1()` в

```
try {
    f1();
} catch (ThatException&)
{
    throw F1Exception();
}
```

(соответственно, `f2()` в свой блок), либо пишем функцию-обертку

```
void f1ex()
{
    try {
        f1();
    } catch (ThatException&)
    {
        throw F1Exception();
    }
}
```

(опять же - свою для `f2()`) и вызываем ее. `F1Exception` можно сделать наследником `ThatException` - того самого исключения, которое `f1` и `f2` генерируют. Тогда можно будет не делать отдельные блоки, а проверять, скажем, с помощью `dynamic_cast`, кто именно сгенерирован. Или сделать одно исключение `FException` с полем, которое будет указывать, где оно сгенерировано.

- код функций ваш, вы можете его менять.

Если генерация исключения выполняется именно вашим кодом - делаете исключения разными, или одним с добавлением поля, или разными, но унаследованными от общего. Если `f1`/`f2` вызывают нечто, что может дать одинаковые исключения - то как выше, оборачивайте эти вызовы в блоки try-catch или в функции-обертки.

*"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не можете добавлять классы исключений, но можете изменить существующие, то можно использовать такой вариант: добавьте в класс исключения поле которое будет хранить информацию о контексте в котором возникло исключение (имя функции например).